# dropdown in navbar : items don't appear

Tags: html, angular6, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want a dropdown that contain item but the item doesn't appear in dropdown.i use a code from bootstrap site officiel.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary ">
    
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add new article</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <div class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Categorie
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                          <div class="dropdown-item">Another action</div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <div class="dropdown-item">Another action</div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <div class="dropdown-item">Something else here</div>
                        </li>
                    
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    
</nav>
```

thanks, i need a help

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your **dropdown** to this below:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu mt-3">
    <a class="dropdown-item"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Edit Profile</a>
    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item">
      <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>Logout
    </a>
</div>
```